# How to catch NPE when a key is null in a List with JDO on GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am getting the following exception on App Engine when accessing a field which is defined like

```
@Persistent(mappedBy = "shelf")
@Element(dependent = "true")
private List<ShelfData> shelfData = new ArrayList<ShelfData>();
```

I presume from looking at [the code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java) that there is an item in the list which is null. How it got there I don't know, since all my inserts are wrapped in transactions. However, what I would really like to do is catch the error (and ignore it, or even delete the offending item).

```
Uncaught exception from servlet

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchGetBySize(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.get(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:275)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl$1.runInternal(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:29)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.get(WrappedDatastoreService.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.getCollectionFromDatastoreObject(FetchFieldManager.java:666)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchRelationField(FetchFieldManager.java:483)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.FetchFieldManager.fetchObjectField(FetchFieldManager.java:405)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replacingObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2353)
    at com.myapp.model.Shelf.jdoReplaceField(Shelf.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Shelf.jdoReplaceFields(Shelf.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1935)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceFields(JDOStateManager.java:1962)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:567)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadFieldsFromDatastore(JDOStateManager.java:1638)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.loadSpecifiedFields(JDOStateManager.java:1240)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.isLoaded(JDOStateManager.java:1728)
    at com.myapp.model.Shelf.jdoGetshelfData(Shelf.java)
    at com.myapp.model.Shelf.getShelfData(Shelf.java:137)
    ...
```

Fixing the data is obviously the eventual plan, but I'm not sure how to go about that since as soon as I access the field its going to throw this error.

Comment: Isn't there a local data viewer ? and does it allow updates ? so you could then correct the erroneous entry

Comment: There is a datastore viewer, but you can't edit lists, and in any case the list contains several thousand items by now

Comment: and the low-level API allows update of such a thing ? if so just get the Entity in question and update the field (assuming GAE low-level doesn't bomb out with that same exception)

Comment: @NeilStockton I did end up writing some low-level code to fix the data. For some reason I couldn't do it in the middle of a JDO transaction, but it works even if it is pretty ugly!